# send http get service requests within loop in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am having an array of product ids and wanted to send http get requests based on the id from the array which is looped. Can any one please help.

service :

```
addedProductIdArray : string[] =[];//this array has the list of ids which is getting updated from many other components
```

Now I need a method in this service which gets the id from the array and send http get request with the url appended by id.

Example:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= this._cartService.addedProductIdArray.length; i++)
this._http.get("https://someurl/shopping-cart/"+this._cartService.addedProductIdArray[i])
```

The response from each request is a JSON array which when collected together will give me a list of products that I will display on my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with RXJS and the forkJoin op:

```
const reqs = [];
reqs.push(this._http.get(url));
return Observable.forkJoin(reqs).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I got struck at this. Could you please see the error in the cart page by adding products in this page - https://angular-rqozhm.stackblitz.io/products

The code is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqozhm?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.service.ts and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqozhm?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts

Comment: The observable.forkjoin is reurning [object object]. How do I get its value?

Comment: Subscribe to it: `Observable.forkJoin(...).subscribe((requests: any[]) => {
// requests will be array of observables with responses`

Comment: Thank you @bc1105